# Conflicting package reappears after deletion

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have taken on somebody else's ASP.NET MVC 5 project, and I am having a small problem compiling it (unfortunately, the original author is not available).

The error I am getting is:

```
The type 'System.Threading.LazyInitializer' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll' and 'c:\Data\Poseidon\Poseidon\packages\TaskParallelLibrary.1.0.2856.0\lib\Net35\System.Threading.dll'
```

Now, in Windows Explorer, I have tried deleting the TaskParallelLibrary from the solution's packages directory. This method has worked in the past to resolve such conflicts. However, the strange thing is that when I now build the project, this package somehow reappears back in the packages directory. Hence, the error message reappears.

So, I have two questions:

1. What might it be that is causing this package to reappear even after I delete it?
2. Is simply deleting the package, which conflicts with the .NET library, the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remove reference to this package from packages.config file in your projects.
Or simply open Nuget packages manager (you can find it if you'll right click on Solution in explorer).

Most probably currently your solution is configured to restore all missing packages on every build [Using NuGet without committing packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages)